# ¿Cómo ejecutar código RAILS descargado de github con RBENV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github

Descargue este codigo en github:
https://github.com/jvazquezolivares/app-administrativa-rails

No logro hacerlo funcionar. He corrido varios comandos rails y rbenv, pero sin resultados favorables.

Trabajo rbenv y uso ruby 2.5 para esta proyecto. Ya intente esto y no funciono:

- gem install bundler
- bundle install
- bundle update
- gem install rails -v 5.2.4
- RBENV_VERSION=2.5.0 rbenv exec gem install rails --version 5.2.4 --no-document

Errores obtenidos:

CASO 1

```
/app-administrativa-rails $ RBENV_VERSION=2.5.0 rbenv exec gem install rails -v 5.2.4 --no-document
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /private/var/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10/ext/mimemagic
/private/var/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/ruby -rrubygems /private/var/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/private/var/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.5.0/mimemagic-0.3.10 RUBYLIBDIR=/private/var/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.5.0/mimemagic-0.3.10
rake aborted!
Could not find MIME type database in the following locations: ["/usr/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/homebrew/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml"]

Ensure you have either installed the shared-mime-info package for your distribution, or
obtain a version of freedesktop.org.xml and set FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH to the location
of that file.

This gem might be installed as a dependency of some bigger package, such as rails, activestorage,
axlsx or cucumber. While most of these packages use the functionality of this gem, some gems have
included this gem by accident. Set USE_FREEDESKTOP_PLACEHOLDER=true if you are certain that you
do not need this gem, and wish to skip the inclusion of freedesktop.org.xml.

The FREEDESKTOP_PLACEHOLDER option is meant as a transitional feature, and will be deprecated in
the next release.

Tasks: TOP => default
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /private/var/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /private/var/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.5.0/mimemagic-0.3.10/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás teniendo problemas con `mimemagic`. Para MacOs, prueba con homebrew instalando:

```
brew install shared-mime-info
```

Para Ubuntu/Debain-based, prueba con:

```
sudo apt-get install shared-mime-info
```